# Nexus group by SNAPSHOT

Tags: maven, nexus

I have Nexus with **builds** repository. How I can group my versions on folders named snapshot-x.x ?

Repository have `snapshot` type. User deployment have all privileges.
I run maven as `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=$VERSION` and `mvn clean deploy -B -Pbuild -Dbuild.version=$VERSION`

My settings.xml work only releases repo ;-(

```
    <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                              http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <servers>
    <server>
    </server>
  </servers>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>build</id>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>nexus-repo</id>
          <name>Nexus repo</name>
          <url>http://<MY-HOST>:8081:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
        <id>nexus-repo</id>
        <name>Nexus repo </name>
        <url>http://<MY-HOST>:8081/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
        <releases>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
      </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
      <properties>
        <altDeploymentRepository>
          -DaltDeploymentRepository=builds::default::http://deployment:<MY_PASS>@<MY-HOST>:8081/content/repositories/builds
        </altDeploymentRepository>
      </properties>
    </profile>

  </profiles>

</settings>

<activeProfiles>
  <activeProfile>build</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Comment: I doubt that you can change the internal format of the repository. Furthermore, it seems strange to group different jars by version because versions should be independent (one may change while the others stay the same). Can you explain us your idea (why you want to restructure the repository)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are asking for? A repository has a fixed format which comprises of groupId:artifactId:version ?

[image]

There you see com/soebes/examples/j2ee is the groupId: `com.soebes.examples.j2eee` and than artifactId: `app` plus the version `1.1.2-SNAPSHOT` with the underlying versions for a single SNAPSHOT

Comment: Now I have the following hierarchy: `com->soebes->examples->[app,service,ui and other] -> version`.

But I want: `com->soebes->examples->SNAPSHOTSx.x->[app,service,ui, other]->versions`.